# How to prevent the default action of urllib2.Request class from capitalizing the header in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

How to prevent the default action of urllib2.Request class from capitalizing the header in python 2.7.When I create a urllib2.Request class instance and pass headers by default in does capitalization of headers passed, instead I want headers to be in uppercase when i do a request.How can i do the same. Webservice where i do a request accepts headers in capitals(example HTTP_REQUEST_VAL).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You appear to be confusing CGI standard treatment of headers with required headers. `HTTP_REQUEST_VAL` is the CGI version of the `Request-Val` HTTP header, **not** that the header is being matched case-sensitively.

Comment: And to be clear: the `HTTP_REQUEST_VAL` environment variable is set by capitalizing HTTP headers, replacing dashes with underscores, and prepending `HTTP_` to the header name. This also means that (as required by the HTTP RFC standard) header matching is *case insensitive*.

Answer (score 5):

HTTP header names are case-insensitive as per the spec, but if your webservice seems to have problems with that, you'll have to resort to some hacks, as the title casing is hardwired into urllib2. There's no getting around it unless you want to subclass half of the library just to get rid of it.

An alternative would be to subclass `str` and use `SafeString('foo')` instead of `'foo'` for the header name, but that seems like a bad hack:

```
class SafeString(str):
    def title(self):
        return self

    def capitalize(self):
        return self
```

A better solution would be to use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which doesn't modify your headers:

```
import requests

requests.get('http://example.com', headers={
    'EXAMPLE-header': 'foo'
})
```

Comment: Note that the OP is most likely confused by the CGI standard setting environment variables from headers in all-caps with underscores and `HTTP_` pre-pended. Setting the `Request-Val` header is more than likely what is required here, *not* fudging with the request headers client-side.

Comment: r.headers['HTTP_REQUEST_VAL'] = 'foo' doesn't work  it capitalizes headers

Comment: @carol: I guess urllib2 is more broken than I thought. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Override the add_adder functionality

```
import urllib.request

class CustomHttp(urllib.request.Request):
    def add_header(self, key, value):
        self.headers[key] = value

req = CustomHttp(url, data=data, headers=headers, method="POST")
```

and continue as it is.